# I would like to Prevent categories from being overwritten during woocommerce csv Product upload

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to Prevent categories from being overwritten during woocommerce csv  Product upload.
When updating products useing built in woocommerce csv importer i  would like to prevent existing categories from being overwritten so that product remains in existing categories and is also added to new categories.
Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

LFC

Comment: Have you checked this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/).?

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading through the woocommerce csv upload, be sure to tick the box of "update matching products". if in your CSV you don´t have a column for your categories and you don´t map it, the category related to that product should not be affected whatsoever.

If you want to add a new product to a new category, then you should add the column category in the CSV and map it with the categories (and don´t tick the update matching products box)

If it is a product that it´s already in your page and you want to assign it a new category then you should tick the previously mentioned box and assign the category in the CSV (make sure that the category name is EXACTLY the same).

Btw i believe this kind of questions are not accepted in SO, you should always provide the steps you have tried and a code snippet if possible. Maybe this question is more fitted in a WooCommerce forum.